# Pardot form handler submission via API

Tags: api, form, pardot, post

I have a Pardot form handler linked to a form on a company's webpage. I need to do a test submission via API. I am making a POST request to the form handler endpoint URL and I filled every field but I get the error message "Please correct the following errors: - This field is required". There are required fields in the form but I filled them all, so I don't uderstand why I am getting the error.
Does anyone know what is wrong with my request?

This is the code I am using (on the left is the name HTML of the form field on the website, on the right the value with which I want to fill the field):

```
{
"Language":"italian",
"email": "test1611@test.com",
"Consenso trattamento dati":true,
"Consenso condivisione dati":true,
"Tipologia" : "Iscritti Newsletter",
"phone" : "12344566",
"country": "IT",
"First Name": "MARIO",
"zip":"10149",
"Last Name":"ROSSI"
}
```

This is the error I get:
[image]

Thanks

Paola

Answer (score 0):

When using postman to submit form handler requests (or API requests), you need to use `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of a `raw` body with JSON.

You are getting "required fields missing" as from Pardot's perspective you are not sending any data at all.