# Pardot FormHandler via API

Tags: form, pardot

How I can send data to Pardot FormHandler via API. And get the JSON response as in this question: [Pardot form handler submission via API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/326465/pardot-form-handler-submission-via-api)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually mixing 2 technologies here.

Pardot's Form handler only accepts a `x-url-form-encoded` payload which "returns" a URL to be redirected to. If there's a validation error at the Form Handler level, the redirect URL will contain the error details. JSON is not possible here (unless you want to pass a JSON string as a value to one of the fields)

Pardot's API is a different way to work with Pardot, and would require a little bit of coding on your end to make it work, including OAuth to get an access token and making API requests to get your data in (in a way that doesn't create duplicates).

Working with V3 or V4 of the API, you need to specify `format=json` as a URL parameter to the API request. V5 of the API is JSON.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the description of the question I was referring to https://prnt.sc/23ocg4z, but I thought he just sent a Post request to the formHandler endpoint.
If it still sent a request via the API, can I run submit formHandler via the API or not? I would like to be able to configure Completion Actions via the web interface.

Comment: A Form Handler can take a simple POST request with x-url-form-encoded content. The API can provide a JSON response. You can't submit a form handler with the API, there are no endpoints for doing so.

Comment: Pardot API and Pardot Form Handlers are completely different technologies / systems / code.